# Optionally Lazy Parameters

Tags: c++, c++14, lazy, closure

Inspired by Swift's `@autoclosure` feature, I tried writing a brief C++-14 header that permits "optionally" lazy parameters (by "lazy" I mean `@autoclosure`-like; I chose the word "lazy" in emulation of lazy evaluation in languages such as Haskell). From [this post on interesting Swift features](http://krakendev.io/blog/hipster-swift#autoclosure):

> The `@autoclosure` attribute delays the execution of a function that's activated in a function parameter. Essentially, calling a function inside of a parameter will wrap the function call in a closure for later use in the function body.

I provide a macro, `LAZY_PARAM`, that can be applied to *parameters* in function declarations; when calling these functions, arguments must be supplied using either the `LAZY_ARG` macro, which uses reference-based closure-semantics to delay evaluation of the expression, or the `EAGER_ARG` macro, which immediately evaluates the expression and wraps it in a light-weight class that simply stores the result. It's copied below and also available [here](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/PublicPaste/tree/master/GenericCppCode/OptionalLaziness). (**NOTE:** The linked version, on GitHub, will be kept up-to-date as I make changes, but the copied version may not.)

```
#pragma once

#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// Uses dynamic dispatch to permit lazy OR eager argument evaluation at the
// caller's discretion, with uniform access to the final value from the callee's
// perspective.
template <typename VAL_TYPE>
class LazyType_Base
{
  protected:
    // For LazyType_TrueLazy
    template <typename CALLABLE>
    LazyType_Base(CALLABLE&& expr)
    { 
      static_assert(
          std::is_same<
              typename std::remove_reference<decltype(expr())>::type, VAL_TYPE
            >::value,
          "Expression does not evaluate to correct type!");
    }
    // For LazyType_Eager
    // =default is not permitted by GCC here; see
    // https://stackoverflow.com/q/38213809/1858225
    LazyType_Base(void) {}

  public:
    // Both compilers suddenly fail when this is introduced, attempting to
    // instantiate `LazyType_Base<LazyType_Base<VAL_TYPE>>`, which makes no
    // sense. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38214138/1858225
    // In general, not making the destructor virtual *should* be safe as long as
    // users are just using this type as it's intended (i.e. for lazy arguments
    // to functions, to be used immediately or discarded without passing
    // pointers around for deletion later).
    // virtual ~LazyType_Base(void) =default;

    virtual operator VAL_TYPE(void) =0;
};

// Takes an arbitrary expression and creates a class that will evaluate the
// expression when necessary.
template <typename VAL_TYPE, typename CALLABLE>
class LazyType_TrueLazy : public LazyType_Base<VAL_TYPE>
{
  // friend LazyType_TrueLazy<VAL_TYPE, CALLABLE> MakeLazy<CALLABLE>(CALLABLE&& expr);
  // With a working friend declaration, make all constructors private; `protect`
  // default constructors in `LazyType_Base`

  public:
    LazyType_TrueLazy(CALLABLE&& expr)
      : LazyType_Base<VAL_TYPE>{std::forward<CALLABLE>(expr)}
      , expr_{std::forward<CALLABLE>(expr)}
    {}

    operator VAL_TYPE(void) override final
    {
      return expr_();
    }

  private:
    CALLABLE expr_;
};

// If VAL_TYPE is the same as EXPR_TYPE, then we do not have a truly lazy
// instantiation.
template <typename VAL_TYPE>
class LazyType_Eager : public LazyType_Base<VAL_TYPE>
{
  public:
    LazyType_Eager(
        VAL_TYPE&& final_val)
      : LazyType_Base<VAL_TYPE>{}
      , val_{final_val}
    {}

    operator VAL_TYPE(void) override final
    {
      return val_;
    }

  private:
    VAL_TYPE val_;
};

// C++14: since template `auto` arguments are not permitted prior to C++17,
// we need a helper function to evaluate the type of the callable, in case it's
// a lambda.
template <typename CALLABLE>
auto MakeLazy(CALLABLE&& expr)
{
  return LazyType_TrueLazy<
            typename std::remove_reference<decltype(expr())>::type, CALLABLE>{
      std::forward<CALLABLE>(expr)};
}

#define LAZY_ARG(expr) \
  MakeLazy([&](void)->auto { return expr; })

// Is there some way to create an implicit conversion to `LazyType_Eager` for
// all types that will be applied for any attempted conversion to
// `LazyType_Base`?
#define EAGER_ARG(val) \
  LazyType_Eager<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(val)>::type>{val}

// Must provide a REFERENCE so that the actual type will not be sliced...but we
// don't actually want a mutable reference to a long-lived object, so we take an
// r-value reference. This is very simple to use with the `LAZY_ARG` and
// `EAGER_ARG` macros.
#define OPTIONALLY_LAZY(type) \
  LazyType_Base<type>&&
```

I've also created a short program to test it:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "OptionallyLazy.hpp"

void PermitLazy(
    OPTIONALLY_LAZY(int) my_int)
{
  std::cout << "Called 'PermitLazy'." << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Got possibly-lazy int: " << my_int << std::endl;
}

int ExpensivelyGenerateInt(void)
{
  std::cerr << " <[( Generating int (pretend this call is expensive)! )]> ";
  std::cerr.flush();
  return 7;
}

int main(void)
{
  PermitLazy(LAZY_ARG(ExpensivelyGenerateInt()));
  PermitLazy(EAGER_ARG(ExpensivelyGenerateInt()));
  PermitLazy(EAGER_ARG(3));
  // See comment above `EAGER_ARG`
  // PermitLazy(ExpensivelyGenerateInt());
}
```

In the above "test" code, `STDERR` is interleaved with `STDOUT` in a way that demonstrates that indeed the `EAGER` expression is evaluated immediately, while the `LAZY` expression is evaluated after the `Called 'PermitLazy'` print-statement.

The above code compiles with G++ 5.1 and Clang++ 3.7.

I'd like to know:

- Does this seem like a reasonable idea for a lightweight library? Is there anything similar that's already available? I like the idea of it for functions that may or may not require actually using particular arguments, e.g. in a logger with a "sensitivity level": when the sensitivity level is below the severity level, there's no reason to actually construct the log-entry string, and in some cases this might actually be rather expensive (e.g. when dumping an entire JSON tree for debugging purposes).
- Ideally, I'd like to be able to implicitly convert *any* type to a `LazyType_Base<T>&&` by automatically creating a `LazyType_Eager` without requiring the `EAGER_ARG` macro. I think this would make usage a little simpler and improve code readability at the call-site. Is there any way to accomplish this? (I don't think it's possible to create a constructor in a base class that creates an instance of a particular derived class under-the-hood, because...that makes no sense. And I can't think of another way to accomplish this.)
- Are there any hidden pitfalls that people can see? Any other improvements I can make?

**EDIT: links to SO questions:**

- [G++ doesn't permit use of `=default` constructor for base-class template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38213809/1858225)
- [Existence of virtual destructor changes evaluation of seemingly-unrelated expression's type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38214138/1858225) **SOLVED**

**EDIT: other known issues:**

- **`const`-correctness:** This apparently does not work "out-of-the-box" for `const` types. I'm not sure why, but the compiler errors seem to indicate that this creates a temporary object of type `LazyType_Base`, which can't be done because it's pure-virtual. I don't know exactly why using a `const` value-type causes the creation of the temporary, though, when the non-`const` version does not.

Comment: Can you add a link to for `@autoclosure` and `Lazy Parameters`. This is not something I have heard of before.

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks for the suggestion; I've provided a link and quoted the `@autoclosure` definition. "Lazy parameters" is not a technical term AFAIK, but simply my chosen term for what I'm doing here; I'm drawing on the idea of eager versus lazy evaluation (e.g. when comparing languages like Haskell, which do lazy evaluation, to "eager" languages like C++).

Comment: The version on this question can't be updated as you make changes, aside from changes to make the question on-topic.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Is that a rule specific to CodeReview? This is (as you can see) my first question, and I'm not familiar with that rule.

Comment: @KyleStrand It is. Sorry, I didn't realize you were new here -- welcome! In broad strokes, questions have to be about real, working code (which yours is, assuming you didn't put a placeholder or broken library there) and once the code is up, it can't be modified, unless the question is off-topic for some reason and you're fixing it. I'd recommend reading through [some](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) articles, and poking through the most popular questions and answers on Meta. They explain better than I can.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Ah, I see--yes, I understand the rationale behind not changing code once I've received answers (since it would presumably invalidate parts of the answers), but I haven't received any answers yet and I've already made (minor) changes.

Comment: @Kyle the problem is that someone may have started to review your question already, but not finished. Very minor changes are probably fine, but in general it's better to be overly cautious and say that no changes at all should be made. If people want to see the up-to-date code, they can look at GitHub (which, of course, you can edit as you see fit.)

Answer (score 2):

> Does this seem like a reasonable idea for a lightweight library? Is there anything similar that's already available? I like the idea of it for functions that may or may not require actually using particular arguments, e.g. in a logger with a "sensitivity level"

Well, passing parameters lazily sounds like a good idea; but I don't really see why the callee needs to be aware of both "lazy" and "non-lazy" params. In other words, I would reimplement your whole library as three lines:

```
#define OPTIONALLY_LAZY(T) std::function<T()>
#define LAZY_ARG(e) [&](){ return e; }
#define EAGER_ARG(e) [_x=(e)](){ return _x; }
```

and then force the callee to be implemented as

```
void PermitLazy(
    OPTIONALLY_LAZY(int) my_int)
{
  std::cout << "Called 'PermitLazy'." << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Got possibly-lazy int: " << my_int() << std::endl;
}
```

(notice the one extra set of parentheses in `my_int()` there).

Furthermore, I would offer the caller the option to lazily compute the value on first reference and then cache that value for all future references:

```
#define LAZY_MEMOIZED_ARG(e) \
    [&, _first=true, _x=decltype(e){}]() mutable { \
        if (_first) { _x = (e); _first = false; } \
        return e; \
    }
```

You certainly *can* reinvent-the-wheel of `std::function<T(void)>` while you're at it, but you don't *need* to reinvent it. The standard one will probably be faster than your thing.

---

Implicit conversions (e.g. your `operator T()`) are the devil and should be avoided. For example, consider the semantics of `std::max(my_int, 0)` with your library (and compare to the semantics of `std::max(my_int(), 0)` with my three-liner). Also consider what happens if you pass your `my_int` to a function expecting a `const int&`. (Off the top of your head, what does it do? What *should* it do? Now try it — what does it *really* do?)

Raw rvalue references (e.g. your `LazyType_Base<type>&&`) are also a code smell to be avoided; in these cases, if you can't take by const lvalue reference, you usually ought to be taking by value.

---

Your `[&](void)->auto {...}` is just a very long-winded way of writing `[&]{...}`. Personally I do write `[&](){...}` with the "unnecessary" parentheses, and wouldn't dock you for those; but writing out `(void)` in C++, or writing `->auto` at all, is definitely unidiomatic.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your very first comment: "I don't really see why the callee needs to be aware of both "lazy" and "non-lazy" params." You then show an implementation that forces the callee to use `()` to get the actual value, but I don't see what this has to do with "understanding" lazy and non-lazy params.

Comment: Additionally, your guess that `std::function` is faster is actually not correct; I've added some trivial benchmarking to the Git repository and run it a couple times on my machine. You can look at the git repo to see exactly what I did, but with 10,000,000 calls to an "optionally lazy" function, `std::function` took about 1.14 seconds for lazy args and 0.68 seconds for eager args, while my implementation took about 0.26 seconds and 0.18 seconds, respectively.

Comment: This makes sense with what I've heard about the general performance of pure lambdas versus `std::function`.

Comment: I feel that forcing the callee to explicitly retrieve the argument value using `()` defeats the entire point of "lazy arguments", but then again attempting to implement lazy evaluation in a low-level eagerly-evaluating language like C++ is definitely running against the grain, and indeed I don't see a way around the fundamental problem that this attempt at deferred evaluation via wrapping types wreaks havoc with template functions like `max`.

Comment: As for the insistence that a particular language feature is "the devil," that feels...contrary to the goals of C++, which seems to be designed to provide anything and everything the committee can think of and leave it up to developers to decide how to use the tools provided. This is why I thought it might be possible to implement this "optionally lazy" thing in the first place.

Comment: The point of the r-value reference is to try to encourage using the "lazy/eager args" as in-place local values rather than, say, heap-allocating them. Since the base type is pure virtual, taking it by value won't work.

Comment: My current coding environment encourages explicit over implicit, hence `[&](void)->auto...` instead of `[&]...`. I've never heard an argument that `function(void)` is unidiomatic for C++, but I haven't read many style guides so you probably know better than I. My current coding environment is also the reason for some other stylistic choices in the code, e.g. having column-aligned function-braces.

Comment: Re "the devil": The committee thinks of many things it doesn't standardize, and standardizes a fair number of things it regrets (see: `gets`, `export` templates, constructors that default to non-`explicit`,...). Implicit conversions are *definitely* on the list of things the committee is trying hard to discourage with C++11 and later; see e.g. how initializer-lists don't allow implicit narrowing conversions. They're like `void*`: sometimes gurus need them, but if you're using them willy-nilly you're almost certainly wrong. Also cf. the number of STL functions that take `foo&&`. (Not many.)

Comment: Re brace placement: I do appreciate that your code is consistently formatted, even if it's not 100% my style of choice. ;) Most people's code on here is just a mess. Yours is nice. Re `(void)`: If you need C compatibility, you must use `(void)`. If you're Bjarne, [you use `()`.](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f43-never-directly-or-indirectly-return-a-pointer-to-a-local-object) Re `->auto`: I've never seen *anyone* do *that*, let alone defend it. We use trailing return types for SFINAE, or explicitness, but never just to repeat the word `auto`! :P

Comment: I actually typically don't write `->auto`; I'm not really sure why I did so here. I suppose I just wanted the macro definition to make it *painfully obvious* that it's a lambda, but you're right, it really isn't adding anything. And thanks for the pointer to the Core guidelines--I'll take that into consideration when deciding whether to use `(void)` on future projects.

Comment: To clarify on `(void)`: Bjarne Stroustrup and Herb Sutter wrote the examples that accompany the Core Guidelines, and you can see that all their examples use `()` not `(void)`. However, the Core Guidelines themselves **do not say** "use `()` not `(void)`" — the Guidelines don't concern themselves with such low-level religious trivia. (Here on CodeReview, on the other hand... ;)) My point was just that `()` is what the experts are *doing* these days, regardless of whether they waste time *saying* it.

Comment: Well, they do say that Dennis Ritchie considered '(void)' to be "an  abomination."

Comment: Actually, yeah, they have **NL.25: Don't use `void` as an argument type**. This is where they mention Ritchie.

Comment: I stand corrected! :D